# 'from path import Path' shows completely different methods than 'import path'

Tags: path

In Python (3.6) why does `from path import Path` output completely different methods than `import path` when `print(dir(path))`?

Comment: Answer might depend on the language.

Comment: Yes, I neglected to state Python (3.6)!